# How to address the pandoc issue

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, pandoc

I encountered a problem when using `saveWidget` in VSCode, which might be caused by `pandoc`.

When I run the following line in Rstudio, it works well and `mtcars.html` can be generated

```
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(DT::datatable(mtcars), "mtcars.html", selfcontained = TRUE, title = "mtcars")
```

However, when I move the same code to VSCode, it gives me an error, saying that

```
Error in htmlwidgets::saveWidget(DT::datatable(mtcars), "mtcars.html",  : 
  Saving a widget with selfcontained = TRUE requires pandoc. For details see:
https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/master/PANDOC.md
```

I suspect VSCode didn't recognize the path to `pandoc`, since I typed `find_pandoc` in VScode to find the version and directory, showing that

```
> rmarkdown::find_pandoc()
$version
[1] '0'

$dir
NULL
```

However, in Rstudio it shows

```
> find_pandoc()
$version
[1] ‘2.7.2’

$dir
[1] "C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc"
```

Comment: I don't know when I started doing it, but I have `Sys.setenv(RSTUDIO_PANDOC="/R/RStudio/bin/pandoc")` in my `~/.Rprofile` (allegedly to not use a pandoc installed outside of R/RStudio). If you set that within your VSCode env, does `find_pandoc()` find it, and does the error go away?

Comment: @r2evans well...it seems the error is still there

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding What does `rmarkdown:::find_program("pandoc")` return inside VSCode? `Sys.getenv("RSTUDIO_PANDOC")`? What about `Sys.which("pandoc")`? All inside VSCode. You may need to add a path to pandoc executable ("C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc") to your system-wide `PATH` variable.

Comment: The problem is that the `RSUDIO_PANDOC` variable is not set to the pandoc path inside VSCode. If adding pandoc to `PATH` helps, I will write a detailed answer.

Comment: @slava-kohut Wow! Thanks a lot. Adding a `PATH` variable to system environment variable get it works! Please write down your answer with details and I will accept that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to understand what is going on, let's take a look at the source code of `rmarkdown:::find_pandoc()`. We can find the following lines there:

```
sys_pandoc <- find_program("pandoc")
sources <- c(Sys.getenv("RSTUDIO_PANDOC"), if (nzchar(sys_pandoc)) dirname(sys_pandoc))
```

`sources` are then used to fetch the `pandoc` path. I suspect that in your case `RSTUDIO_PANDOC` is not set, so `rmarkdown:::find_pandoc()` relies on `find_program("pandoc")` to find the path. If you in turn look at its source code, you will find out that the path is determined by running `Sys.which`, which is equivalent to extracting the path from the shell:

> The system command which reports on the full path names of an
>   executable (including an executable script) as would be executed by a
>   shell...

That being said, you need to add a path to pandoc to the `PATH` environment variable on your system.

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding is my source not reputable enough? Never answered a bountied question before and don't know how this works.

Comment: It seems the system will award the bounty one day after accepting the answer. No worries, I will do that when system allows me to do that.

Comment: You say we need to add a path to pandoc to the `PATH` environment variable on out system but you don't say how to do that. Could you edit your answer to expound on that? I've found where pandoc.exe is but how do I tell R in VSCode where that is? In the VSCode JSON settings?